# Fail to detect SPS30 sensor on Pi 3B I2C

Tags: i2c

[image]I try to connect a [Sensirion SPS30 Particle Sensor](https://www.sensirion.com/en/environmental-sensors/particulate-matter-sensors-pm25/) to my Raspberry Pi 3B via I2C. There are other sensors on the I2C Bus - and they work without any problems, but I fail to detect the SPS30.

What I have tried:

- The SPS30 is connected to 5V, Pins 4 & 5 are connected to GND
- I use a splitter (3K/2K) to connect SDA/SCL, and the I2C lines are all pulled-up to 3V (it doesn't work without any pull-up/pull down resistors, I think I tried many possible combinations)
- I've set the baudrate to 100,000 (dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=100000)

None of this seems to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions what else to try?

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:29:51 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Clear photos showing the connections may help.

Comment: I've added the circuit - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do but this is certainly not the way to do it.

The Pi has pull-ups on I²C lines so none are needed.

The series resistors will effectively prevent anything from working; I²C uses open drain circuitry.

Most I²C devices will work at 3.3V **if there are no pullups to 5V**, occasional devices need higher voltages and require a level converter.

See [rPi3 I2C-LCD, do i need a logic level converter?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75570/rpi3-i2c-lcd-do-i-need-a-logic-level-converter/75580#75580)

Comment: The resistors are to get from 5V to 3.3V on SDA/SCL - I've noticed that the pull-up resistors don't do anything. Bu even when I connect the SPS30 directly to SDA/SCL I can't detect it (e.g. with i2cdetect)

Comment: You obviously don't understand how the circuit works and the bus is bi-directional. You need NO pull-ups on the devices BUT if they have pull-ups you need a level converter.

Comment: Thanks - this explains a lot! I'm sorry, this is my first excursion into this type of electronics, I used to stay away from hardware if possible.

Comment: I have added a Level Converter - but still without success unfortunately. It is connected to 5V on HV and 3.3 V on LV - and SDA and SCL are both passed through.